# What type of repetition is this sentence?

Tags: repetition, poetry

> ‘Tut, she's a lamb, a dove, a fool to him!
>   I'll tell you, Sir Lucentio: when the priest
>   Should ask, if Katharina should be his wife,
>   'Ay, by gogs-wouns,' quoth he; and swore so loud,
>   That, all-amazed, the priest let fall the book;
>   And, as he stoop'd again to take it up,
>   The mad-brain'd bridegroom took him such a cuff
>   That ***down fell priest and book and book and priest***:
>   'Now take them up,' quoth he, 'if any list.'’

What type of repetition is this sentence? For what I know, repetitions is repeating the exact same phrase/word again for emphasis. This sentence sounds a little weird but does it also mean the same way a other repetitive sentences?(As in repeating for emphasis.)

Comment: What is the source? Literary? Some more context perhaps?

Comment: @user3169: You don't recognize "Taming of the Shrew"? Shakespeare?

Comment: I found some here: https://blog.udemy.com/repetition-in-poetry/ . Care to try to identify which it is? :-)  My head started hurting after three or four terms.

Comment: @VictorBazarov Yeah I found that but after half an hour of scouring that list, I couldn't find it. My eyes aren't the best so if anyone can spot it it'll help a lot.

Comment: This looks like a question that would be more appropriate on ELU. You don't seem to be trying to learn English, you're asking about a particular usage of a word.

Comment: @Catija how do I move it there? Or do I have to re-post?

Comment: If you flag it for a moderator and use the custom reason asking for it to be migrated, they can do that for you. Depending on if there's a mod around, that may take a little time. It might be faster for you to post it there yourself and delete the question here. I'm not saying this *isn't* ok here... only that it should be OK there... then again, they may just plop it back over here. I've never been quite able to understand their methodology.

Comment: To me the line has always suggested some sort of sight gag: a bit of actor's business that adds comic exaggeration, such as the priest tumbling head over heels with the book in his arms.